# Identify the extreme end outliers python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have many data frames below are the samples but in actuality, they are huge in size -

one sample - df_all

| Seller | Date | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EWC | 2-Aug-2023 | 26 |
| EWC | 3-Aug-2023 | 27 |
| EWC | 4-Aug-2023 | 40 |
| EWC | 5-Aug-2023 | 50 |
| EWC | 6-Aug-2023 | 60 |
| EWC | 7-Aug-2023 | 76 |
| EWC | 8-Aug-2023 | 106 |
| EWC | 9-Aug-2023 | 126 |
| EWC | 12-Aug-2023 | 1212126 |
| EWC | 13-Aug-2023 | 626 |

Another sample - df_all

| Seller | Date | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BMW | 2-Aug-2023 | 1 |
| BMW | 3-Aug-2023 | 1 |
| BMW | 4-Aug-2023 | 1 |
| BMW | 5-Aug-2023 | 1 |
| BMW | 6-Aug-2023 | 2 |
| BMW | 7-Aug-2023 | 2 |
| BMW | 8-Aug-2023 | 2 |
| BMW | 9-Aug-2023 | 2 |
| BMW | 12-Aug-2023 | 15 |
| BMW | 13-Aug-2023 | 20 |

Here I have 2 seller examples.
EWC on 12th Aug its sales value is 1212126 which is an extreme outlier.
BMW On 12th and 13th Aug its value is 15 and 20 which is not an extreme outlier.

I am using the below code but it is also showing BMW 15 and 20 values as outliers, which is not required. I only need to identify the extreme outliers.

```
        z = np.abs(stats.zscore(df_all['Sales']))
        threshold = 3
        outliers = df_temp[z > threshold]
        print(outliers)
```

Comment: Chech z-score for 20 and set it like trashhold value

Comment: Sorry that wouldn't work

Comment: Do you need a more systematic solution or don’t know how to implement mine?

Comment: Can u please implement yours solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df_all['z'] = np.abs(stats.zscore(df_all['Sales']))
threshold = df_all[df_all.Sales == 20].z.mean()
outliers = df_all[df_all['z']> threshold]
print(outliers)
```

Comment: it`s a low systematic solution but should work for your example

Comment: Sorry, It is not working

Answer (score 0):

Another idea for you:

```
# calculate IQR for column Height
Q1 = df_all['Sales'].quantile(0.10)
Q3 = df_all['Sales'].quantile(0.90)
IQR = Q3 - Q1

# identify outliers
threshold = 1.5
outliers = df_all[(df_all['Sales'] < Q1 - threshold * IQR) |
                  (df_all['Sales'] > Q3 + threshold * IQR)]
```

You can change quantile size for determine threshhold.